# Unexpected result upon using macro

Tags: c++, macros

I was trying to run a code.

```
#include<iostream>
#define CUBE(x)(x*x*x)
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int x=5;
    int y=CUBE(++x);
    cout<<y<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

According to me its output should be 216 but surprisingly its output is coming out to be 392.Someone please help me to get logic behind this.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. View the preprocessed output and you've got http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Comment: `#define CUBE(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))` and `int y=CUBE(x+1);` is probably what you want.

Comment: Putting that define into a function will yield you the requested 216.

Comment: might take the trophy for least helpful title in a SO post yet.

Comment: Your question is tagged C++, so please, for heaven's sake, unless this is an exercise, solve the problem with an inline function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are just textual replacement. Think about what your macro invocation will produce:

```
int y = CUBE(++x);
// becomes
int y = (++x*++x*++x);
```

Modifying a variable more than once between sequence points is undefined behavior (look up "sequence points" for the details). Undefined behavior means that the behavior cannot be relied upon. This is one of the dangers of macros. If it was a function invocation it would work as expected since then `++x` would only be evaluated once.

Comment: `++i, ++i;` or `++i || ++i` are not undefined behaviour so you should say, "Modifying a variable more than once in a sequence point is" (statement --> sequence point)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Lazy wording. I've changed it. Thanks.

Comment: @Grijesh, those are the rules for C++98. In C++11 the rules for sequencing all changed and now it is horrifically complicated. For example, `i = ++i + 1;` is now well-defined (don't ask me to explain, but I read a SO thread about it).

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks MaTT! It has been more than 10 years I didn't use C++. I don't know C++98, 11. But I will read it...

Comment: good luck :) I'm hoping someone will write a detailed, good article on the whole topic.

Answer (score 2):

`CUBE(++x)` expands to `++x * ++x * ++x`. Might be better to define this as an inlined function rather than a define. Something like:

```
inline int CUBE( int x )
{
    return x * x * x;
}
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html

Answer (score 1):

you used macro so the call,

```
CUBE(++x)
```

is replaced by

++x*++x*++x
so the output is not as you predicted.
When you use macro the call is replaced by the code defined in macro.